# java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out at FTPClient.listFiles

Tags: java

I am trying to list the files in CurrentWorkingDirectory on a FTP server using the Apache Commons Net FTPSClient with the code below. I am able to successfully connect and download files using WinSCP.

```
        FTPSClient client = new FTPSClient(true);
        client.setDefaultTimeout(defaultTimeout);
        client.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
        client.setDataTimeout(dataTimeout);
        
        client.connect(server, 990);
        int replyCode = client.getReplyCode();
        if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(replyCode)){
            LOG.error("Unable to connect to server. Error Text=" + client.getReplyString());
        }
        
        if (localActive) {
            setLocalActiveMode();
        } else {
            setLocalPassiveMode();
        }
        
        boolean status = client.login(user, password);
        if (!status) {
            replyCode = client.getReplyCode();
            LOG.error("Login failed. Error Text=" + client.getReplyString());
        }
        setBinaryMode(binaryMode);
        client.changeWorkingDirectory(path);
        
        FTPFile[] files = client.listFiles();
        for (FTPFile file : files) {
```

The Exception raised :

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead(SocketInputStream.java:116)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:171)
   at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(StreamDecoder.java:284)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(StreamDecoder.java:326)
   at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(StreamDecoder.java:178)
   at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:184)
   at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(BufferedReader.java:161)
   at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:324)
   at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(BufferedReader.java:389)
   at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPFileEntryParserImpl.readNextEntry(FTPFileEntryParserImpl.java:53)
   at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPListParseEngine.readStream(FTPListParseEngine.java:128)
   at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPListParseEngine.readServerList(FTPListParseEngine.java:104)
   at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3302)
   at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.initiateListParsing(FTPClient.java:3271)
   at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2930)
   at org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.listFiles(FTPClient.java:2977)
```

[WinSCP session log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z153Z.png)

[WinSCP session log cont..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kh0hw.png)

[WinSCP session log cont..](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d4Ija.png)

[Apache Commons Net log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssP7s.png)

Comment: Yes, WinSCP and Java code is on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

I set the protection buffer size set to 0 & used private data connection (code below & it worked )
client.execPBSZ(0);
client.execPROT("P");